# Can't connect to localhost from Httpful php rest client

Tags: php, httpful

I am using http://phphttpclient.com to try to connect to a simple service running on localhost:8090.

My code is:

```
$url = "http://127.0.0.1:8090/animal-speak";
$response = \Httpful\Request::get($url)
            ->send();
echo "{$response->body}"
```

and I get this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Httpful\Exception\ConnectionErrorException: Unable to connect to "http://127.0.0.1:8090/animal-speak": 7 Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8090: Connection refused in /var/www/vendor/nategood/httpful/src/Httpful/Request.php:1028 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/vendor/nategood/httpful/src/Httpful/Request.php(204): Httpful\Request->buildResponse(false) #1 /var/www/html/index.php(17): Httpful\Request->send() #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/vendor/nategood/httpful/src/Httpful/Request.php on line 1028

I have also tried using Guzzle Http client as well and get exactly the same error which leads me to believe this is a php / libcurl problem? The service is definitely up, I can see it in the browser and can curl to it on the command line.
Thanks

EDIT: if I don't use localhost, and instead use a remote endpoint it works fine.

Comment: It works fine for me with 127.0.0.1:80. Don't you have firewall installed?

Comment: nope, no firewall running. Have had other non-php stuff running on that port and it is fine

Answer (score 0):

my bad.

I was running the service in a Docker container and hadn't setup the network.

My apologies for wasting time!

Comment: could you elaborate? Set up the network? I'm running into this same issue, and also using Docker. I'm running docker-compose for all of my services and I'm not sure what you mean by setting up the network. I can also view the rest api I'm trying to call from the browser, but it's refusing connections from my other service

Comment: how are you running the docker container with the service in? You need to make sure you are mapping the service port to the host port you want to connect on: docker run -p 3000:80 -d myservice/service ...... this will map port 80 inside the docker container onto 3000 on the host